# How to get default gateway in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, routes, netstat, ifconfig

I need to retrieve the default gateway on a Mac machine. I know that in Linux route -n will give an output from which I can easily retrieve this information. However this is not working in Mac OSX(Snow Leopard).

I also tried `netstat -nr | grep 'default'`, but I was hoping for a cleaner output like that produced by `route -n` in Linux/Unix. `netstat -nr` lists all the interfaces and the default gateway for them.

Any kind of suggestion or a hint in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Migrate to SuperUser?

Comment: FYI you can Option + click on WiFi icon on status bar. This shows additional information, including gateway.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You can try with:

```
route -n get default
```

It is not the same as GNU/Linux's `route -n` (or even `ip route show`) but is useful for checking the default route information.
Also, you can check the route that packages will take to a particular host. E.g.

```
route -n get www.yahoo.com
```

The output would be similar to:

```
   route to: 98.137.149.56
destination: default
       mask: 128.0.0.0
    gateway: 5.5.0.1
  interface: tun0
      flags: <UP,GATEWAY,DONE,STATIC,PRCLONING>
 recvpipe  sendpipe  ssthresh  rtt,msec    rttvar  hopcount      mtu     expire
       0         0         0         0         0         0      1500         0
```

IMHO `netstat -nr` is what you need. Even MacOSX's Network utility app(*) uses the output of netstat to show routing information.
[image: Network utility screenshot displaying routing table information]

(*) You can start Network utility with `open /Applications/Utilities/Network\ Utility.app`

Comment: Thanks. You just saved me a few hours at the new house when Time Warner's modem decided it wanted the IP my router used to have, and ifconfig lied about the gateway.

Answer (score 49):

For getting the list of ip addresses associated, you can use **netstat** command

```
netstat -rn
```

This gives a long list of ip addresses and it is not easy to find the required field. The sample result is as following:

```
Routing tables
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.195.1      UGSc           17        0     en2
127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              1   254107     lo0
169.254            link#7             UCS             0        0     en2
192.168.195        link#7             UCS             3        0     en2
192.168.195.1      0:27:22:67:35:ee   UHLWIi         22      397     en2   1193
192.168.195.5      127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0

More result is truncated.......
```

The ip address of gateway is in the first line; one with default at its first column.

To display only the selected lines of result, we can use **grep** command along with **netstat**

```
netstat -rn | grep 'default'
```

This command filters and displays those lines of result having default. In this case, you can see result like following:

```
default            192.168.195.1      UGSc           14        0     en2
```

If you are interested in finding only the ip address of gateway and nothing else you can further filter the result using **awk**. The awk command matches pattern in the input result and displays the output. This can be useful when you are using your result directly in some program or batch job.

```
netstat -rn | grep 'default' | awk '{print $2}'
```

The awk command tells to **match and print the second column** of the result in the text. The final result thus looks like this:

```
192.168.195.1
```

In this case, netstat displays all result, grep only selects the line with 'default' in it, and awk further matches the pattern to display the second column in the text.

You can similarly use route -n get default command to get the required result. The full command is

```
route -n get default | grep 'gateway' | awk '{print $2}'
```

These commands work well in linux as well as unix systems and MAC OS.

Answer (score 12):

The grep utility is not needed. Awk can do it all:

```
    netstat -rn | awk '/default/ {print $2}'
      192.168.128.1
```

Note that if you have something like Parallels (or a VPN, or both) running, you may see two or more default routing entries - it will be true if you use the 'grep' suggestion above, too.

```
    netstat -rn | awk '/default/ {print $2}'
      192.168.128.1
      link#12
```

and

```
    netstat -rn | awk '/default/ {print $2}'                             
      utun1
      192.168.128.1
      link#12
```

To set a variable (_default) for further use (assuming only one entry for 'default') .....

```
    _default=$( netstat -rn inet | awk '/default/ {print $2}' ) # I prefer $( ... ) over back-ticks
```

In the case of multiple default routes use:

```
    netstat -rn | awk '/default/ {if ( index($6, "en") > 0 ){print $2} }'
      192.168.128.1
```

These examples tested in Mavericks Terminal.app and are specific to OSX only. For example, other *nix versions frequently use 'eth' for ethernet/wireless connections, not 'en'.
This is also only tested with ksh. Other shells may need a slightly different syntax.

Comment: if you have multiple default routes, you can limit the output by address family, e.g. for IPv4, use "netstat -f inet", or include the "-f" parameter in the command above.

Answer (score 5):

I would use something along these lines...

```
 netstat -rn | grep "default" | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: How can we achieve this in objective-c programming. Is there any frameork for this

Answer (score 3):

**Using System Preferences:**

Step 1: Click the Apple icon (at the top left of the screen) and select System Preferences.

Step 2: Click Network.

Step 3: Select your network connection and then click Advanced.

Step 4: Select the TCP/IP tab and find your gateway IP address listed next to Router.