# How to get the gateway MAC address in Unix-like systems

Tags: linux, macos, unix, ubuntu, networking

I'm connected to a private network where the IP addresses are like 192.168.xxx.xxx. I know the IP address of the default gateway but how do I get the gateway mac address? I'm working on iMac and Linux machines. Any Unix command for that?

Comment: did you tried "arp -a"?

Comment: Please go to this link: 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782658/how-to-get-default-gateway-in-mac-osx

Answer (score 1):

This gives you list of everything:

```
netstat -rn
```

or this one to get default gateway:

```
netstat -rn | grep 'default'
```

WHAT YOU REALLY WANT:

```
netstat -rn | grep 'default' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: In Centos 7 the output does not include MAC addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Here the command line example for `arping` assuming your gateway's IP address is `192.168.1.1` and you have connected over `eth0`:

```
arping -f -I eth0  192.168.1.1
ARPING 192.168.1.1 from 192.168.1.24 eth0
Unicast reply from 192.168.1.1 [ab:cd:ef:01:02:03]  1.030ms
Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 1 response(s)
```

So in this case gateway's MAC address is `ab:cd:ef:01:02:03`

Comment: I used this solution instead `netstat` because `netstat -rn` does not include MAC addresses in Centos 7.